# Why is there a problem with Turtle module?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm, ide, module-packaging

My turtle module does not work in IDE. Can anyone help me?

Code:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.pen()
```

I wrote this code to make the turtle module open its app, but it didn't happen.

Comment: What happens? What is your *IDE*? What if adding `turtle.done()` at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `turtle.mainloop()` or   `turtle.done()` at the last of the file.

Starts event loop - calling Tkinter’s mainloop function. Must be the last statement in a turtle graphics program. Must not be used if a script is run from within IDLE in -n mode (No subprocess) - for interactive use of turtle graphics.

You can read [turtle document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.done) for more details.